# Local proxy question

Tags: http, proxy

Is it possible to install a proxy locally (on Windows XP) and redirect, for example, all traffic  from "google.com" to "yahoo.com".

If I call http://www.google.com/test it should redirect it to http://www.yahoo.com/test and return the response from yahoo.

Long story short : I have an old program and there is a URL used in it (for a Web service), but the value of the URL is compiled in the app. 
For now, it's connecting in production but I'd like to make some tests in QA, so I would just redirect the URL "http://prod.webservice.website.com" to "http://qa.webservice.website.com" without having to recompile the old application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will do the job. It's a local proxy that is capable of transforming requests.

Comment: I think I found something. I'm going to test it later and report on it.

Comment: It works. Just edit the CustomRules.js file and insert that line in the method OnBeforeRequest :
if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.google.ca")) oSession.hostname = "www.yahoo.com"; 
It will redirect google.ca traffic to yahoo.
To access the file, go to Rules, Customize Rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a host file (or edit), if it's just your computer.  Would that suffice?

Comment: Yes, that's my "last resort". Since I don't have admin rights on the machine, I'll have to ask the support (it takes time here)